# setting a condition to the combo box

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, combobox

I am displaying some com port values in the combo box during run time. I need to select a com port value and then if i press the connect button my process should happen else it should display an error message. What should I do for the condition ?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


    try {
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();

        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\Scratch 2\\Scratch 2.exe C:\\Program Files\\Robotix\\fwdbckpwm12.sb2");


        A4S a4sObj = new A4S(new String[]{jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString()}); 


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(serialportselection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

This button1 is Connect button and when i press this button my file will open but only if my combo box value is selected.

```
  public void addData()
{
     ListSerialPorts listSerPortObj = new ListSerialPorts();



   listData = listSerPortObj.LoadComPorts2();
    for (int index = 0; index < listData.size(); index++)
    {
         str = (String) listData.get(index);
         System.out.println(str);               
         jComboBox2.addItem(str);
   }
```

and this is how I add data to my combo box from another java class. Help me to give a condition to my connect button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
if (jComboBox2.getSelectedItem() == null) { //port is not selected
   System.out.println("Port is not selected");
} else { //port is selected. 
   try {
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();

        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\Scratch 2\\Scratch 2.exe C:\\Program Files\\Robotix\\fwdbckpwm12.sb2");


        A4S a4sObj = new A4S(new String[]{jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString()}); 


    } catch (IOException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(serialportselection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```